# Capturing a cell in a range variable

Tags: excel, vba

Anyone see what is wrong with this code. I'm getting an 'object required' error:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheet2.ChartObjects("myChart").BottomRightCell.Address
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but it won't work. I need to on to be able to do:

r.row and r.column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Range` is not an `Address` — that's a `String`. `BottomRightCell` returns a `Range`.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheet2.ChartObjects("myChart").BottomRightCell

add = r.Address
row = r.Row
col = r.Column
```